# Rollgarch - how to extract forecast dates

Tags: r, time-series

Rugarch's `rollgarch` function: Is there a simple way to get forecasts with dates as xts series?

I'm trying to use `rollgarch` to calculate forecasted volatility for each day over 10yrs. I know that volatility forecasts are stored here:

```
mod@forecast$density$Sigma
```

However when I want to plot them or extract them they are not extracted as an xts so time indices are lost. `index(mod@forecast$density)` gives indices as numbers so that does not help either.

Indexes as dates are very important to me as I want to merge this output with another dataset and use it in a regression.

Also, I always get 5-10 non-converging models and want to be able to see where they are and replace them with something that makes sense.

I fit the model using:

```
mod = ugarchroll(ervol.garch.spec , data = er, n.ahead = 1, 
                 n.start = 150, refit.every = 5, refit.window = "moving", 
                 window.size = 100, solver = "hybrid")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to extract what you want would be

```
tail(mod@model$index, -mod@model$n.start)
```

which is of POSIXct class, while another way would be

```
rownames(mod@forecast$density)
```

where you may then additionally use `as.Date`.

Comment: Thanks. Then `garchvol <- xts(mod@forecast$density$Sigma, as.Date(rownames(mod@forecast$density)))` indeed gives me what I want. Seems like a workoround, but it's good enough.

Comment: @Djpengo, looking at `str(mod)` it doesn't seem that those dates could be somewhere else, so probably one can't do better than this.